# Inconsistent behaviour of AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification when disconnecting bluetooth device

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, avaudiosession

For an application I'm developing, I have an audioManager class where amongst other things I handle AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioSession.

This class is observer of `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`.
When for instance playing an audio through `AVAudioPlayer` I connect a bluetooth headset I get a notification `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable` and when disconnecting 
`AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable` as it should be.

The weird part comes when I have set `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`:
enabling the bluetooth headset grants me the usual `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable` but when disconnecting it what I get is `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOverride`.

I've being searching in Apple's documentation, SO and googled it but haven't found a reason for this behaviour.

One of the things I allow in my app is to route the audio to the speaker using the `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker`. I have a case to handle few changes when I get to that reason override in the notification. So getting there because I have disconnected the bluetooth is far from optimal.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this happens?

Comment: Even I am facing this issue. How did you solved this issue?